# Появление ошибки tshark: Syntax error near ">" при попытке запуска с параметрами

Tags: c#

В данном коде я пытаюсь запустить tshark с параметрами, которые изначально вписываются в консоль. в итоге я должен получить *.txt файл. После "1>" в консоли записывается директория и название файла. Но после запуска команды tshark ругается на синтаксическую ошибку

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

//Запуск Tshark с заданными параметрами
Process LaunchTshark = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo LaunchInfoTshark = new ProcessStartInfo();
LaunchInfoTshark.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
LaunchInfoTshark.Arguments = "-C \"PHY Parameters\" -r C:\\enb_11.11-14-03.pcap 1> \"C:\\enb_11.11-14-03.txt\"";
LaunchTshark.StartInfo = LaunchInfoTshark;
LaunchTshark.Start();
LaunchTshark.WaitForExit();
```

Вот такая ошибка
`tshark: Syntax error near ">"`

Comment: пожалуйста не ставьте метку c#-faq .........  у неё есть специальное назначение, которая к простым вопросам не относится

Comment: `LaunchInfoTshark.UseShellExecute = true;` либо используйте `cmd.exe /C` (или `/K`), а путь к приложению как аргументы для него. Потому что `1>` это шелл фича, а не приложения.

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь, все получилось